# What audio encodings are supported on Android Emulator?

Tags: android

I am trying a small program on the emulator

```
  int frequency=8000;   
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT;
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);

I keep getting bufferSize -2.
```

hwaudioInput:yes is set for the emulator.

For what values should this work? Or do you have any other ideas why this is not working?
Is there way to check why getMinBufferSize fails? What is the exact error message?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you set `freq` to 44100 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

int frequency=8000;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;

```
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
```